# Unable to link volume to the rocker/rstudio container on linux

Tags: docker, rstudio

When I execute commands in Ubuntu 18:

```
cd ~/r-projects
docker run -d -v $PWD:/home/rstudio rocker/rstudio
```

docker creates rstudio container accessible in `localhost:8787`. But I can't see the content of the `$PWD` inside RStudio session. When I save files in RStudio session and then restart the container those files persist, but I can not find them in the host using `locate` command. It seems that `$PWD` is not mounted but docker uses another folder to preserve RStudio state.

This is strange behavior. What I really want is to link some folder on the host to the rstudio inside docker container. What am I doing wrong?

Official [instructions](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine) did not help me.

Please, provide correct command.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=123 -v $PWD:/home/rstudio rocker/rstudio
```

The problem was that I executed commands inside kubernetes cluster.